# The strange nginx log record

Tags: nginx

I use custom log format for my nginx server that look like the following:

```
log_format combine '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $http_host '
'$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
'"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" '
'"$upstream_addr" "$upstream_status" $upstream_cache_status "$upstream_http_content_type" "$upstream_response_time" > $request_time';
```

All works fine ut sometimes I get the very strange empty logs:

```
[13/Mar/2014:08:09:22 +0400] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfinished request. Probably someone connected to you server but fails to ask a request for some reason.

Try following command:

```
telnet yousite.com 80
ctrl-c
```

E.g:

```
$ telnet localhost 2002
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
^]

telnet> Connection closed.
```

and my log:

```
[13/Mar/2014:11:29:54 +0400] - 127.0.0.1 "-" 400 "-" "-" "-" "-" "-" - [proxy (-) : - - ] 0 "-" 0.000
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how could I know ip that client?

Comment: Your empty log in different format. I guess you have some default server which is used because request did not ask specific host. And this default server use different log format.

Comment: What's your opinion according this? It it critical for production server?

Comment: No, if the number of such requests reasonably small. In wild web there are always a few number of clients that has established connection but failed to send request for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the reply again. Could you advise some log format for nginx?

Comment: Log format is really depends on your needs. The only think I could suggest, is to use the same format for all servers in your config, preferably add `access_log ...` to `http` block of your nginx config.